# Excepción Transaction context in use by another session

Tags: c#, session, transacciones, sql-server-2014

Al ejecutar el siguiente código en C# genera la excepción "Transaction context in use by another session."

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            string CONNECTION_STRING = "Data Source=192.168.0.12;Initial Catalog=Pruebas;User ID=UserD;Password=abc123%";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING); 
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO User (Nombre,Paterno,Materno) VALUES ('Juan','Lopez','Lopez') SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", conn);
            int valor = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            Console.WriteLine(valor);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Cabe mencionar que con anterioridad si guardaba la información en SQLServer, alguien sabe como solucionarlo?, gracias.

Después de varias pruebas me di cuenta que el error es directamente en la base de datos (ya reinicie el servicio de sqlserver y sigue igual), de igual manera no deja insertar valores en la tabla desde SQL Server Management Studio

Error de consola:
[image: Error de consola]

Error de SQL Server Management Studio
[image: Error de SQL Server Management Studio]

Comment: y no cierras la conexión?

Comment: Si la cierro, pero aun así muestra la misma excepción

Comment: Por favor incluye el error completo con el stack trace.  Eso implica cambiar el `ex.Message` por `ex.ToString()`, de lo contrario pierdes el stack trace.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún trigger definido en tu tabla `User`?  ¿Puedes incluir el trigger en la pregunta? Por allí debe andar el asunto...

Comment: Me uno al presentimiento que tiene sstan. También veo mucho en internet que los servidores vinculados `Linked Servers` pueden causar este tipo de problema. Me llama mucho la atención una página que dice que se puede haber creado un `Linked Server` sobre el mismo servidor y estar generando una especie de `loop`. El numeral 8 de esta página, da razón de esto: https://www.sswug.org/alexanderchigrik/sql-server/troubleshooting-problems-with-linked-servers-in-sql-server-2014/

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda, después de revisar la base de datos nos dimos cuenta que la tabla User tenia definido un Trigger que insertaba al mismo servidor pero en otra tabla, entonces se eliminó el trigger y ya funciona el código